# android sliding menu getActivity returns null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I've been searching for this for a while now and haven't found any solution so far,

so I have a `sliding menu`, and withing it I call `getActivity()`, so far so good, but when I get out of the app (home button) and come back in a few minutes, the `getActivity()` returns `nullpointerexception`

if anyone has a clue about this it would be much appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be careful about exactly when you call getActivity(). It will return null in any call triggered by the parent activity's lifecycle all the way through onResume(). You have to make sure it is already attached to the parent activity before you can safely call it. Take a look at

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onResumeFragments()

Perhaps it will help you resolve your problem.

Depending on what you're trying to do, I would look into saving a pointer to the activity in the fragment so it can be referenced at times when getActivity might be null. That said, this could be kinda dangerous so be careful if that is the route you choose to take

Comment: thank you for your answer!
I'll try to make a static FragmentActivity object and give to it the activity of the parent each time i resume the app,

Comment: The parent should *be* a fragment activity. All i meant was inside the fragment in perhaps the onAttach(Activity a), save that activity to a local variable and use that reference. I can't imagine you want a reference to a static fragment activity. What exactly are you trying to use the activity for?

Comment: it's the sliding menu from "jfeinstein10", so i thought about getting the activity from the parent that creates the menu, wich is a fragmentactivity

Comment: Yes a reference to that should work if I understand what you're doing correctly.