# IllegalStateException: Fragment <ThisFragment> is not currently in the FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-support-library, illegalstateexception

I have trouble of tracing the cause of the crash in my app. I have a fragment that displays a `ListView`, I also have `SlidingMenu` for a search field. And when I search, the `ListView` items are repopulated basing from the search results. Now, my app crashes when I try to open a `ListView` item from the new populated result.

The exception is triggered here:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", mContent); //Exception made here
}
```

Is this because of the support library? How do I resolve this?

**EDIT:**

Here's the stack trace:

```
02-05 12:51:53.941: E/AndroidRuntime(11638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 12:51:53.941: E/AndroidRuntime(11638): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MyFragment{436749b0} is not currently in the FragmentManager
02-05 12:51:53.941: E/AndroidRuntime(11638):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.putFragment(FragmentManager.java:546)
02-05 12:51:53.941: E/AndroidRuntime(11638):    at com.sample.android.app.SearchListActivity.onSaveInstanceState(SearchListActivity.java:118)
02-05 12:51:53.941: E/AndroidRuntime(11638):    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1137)
02-05 12:51:53.941: E/AndroidRuntime(11638):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1215)
02-05 12:51:53.941: E/AndroidRuntime(11638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:2972)
02-05 12:51:53.941: E/AndroidRuntime(11638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3031)
02-05 12:51:53.941: E/AndroidRuntime(11638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:138)
02-05 12:51:53.941: E/AndroidRuntime(11638):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-05 12:51:53.941: E/AndroidRuntime(11638):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 12:51:53.941: E/AndroidRuntime(11638):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
02-05 12:51:53.941: E/AndroidRuntime(11638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
02-05 12:51:53.941: E/AndroidRuntime(11638):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 12:51:53.941: E/AndroidRuntime(11638):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-05 12:51:53.941: E/AndroidRuntime(11638):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
02-05 12:51:53.941: E/AndroidRuntime(11638):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
02-05 12:51:53.941: E/AndroidRuntime(11638):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT 2:**
Here's my Activity:

```
private Fragment mFragment;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ..........

    params = new Bundle();
    params.putInt("id", id);

    // set the Above View Fragment
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(
                savedInstanceState, "mFragment");
    else {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        SampleListFragment fragment = new SampleListFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(params);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.list_fragment, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    if (mFragment == null) {
        mFragment = new SampleListFragment();
        mFragment.setArguments(params);
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.list_fragment, mFragment).commit();

    // set the Behind View Fragment
    Fragment searchFragment = new SampleSearchFragment();
    searchFragment.setArguments(params);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.activity_search, searchFragment)
            .commit();
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mFragment",
            mFragment);
}
```

And in my `SampleListFragment`, I have this method:

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Activity activity) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Inside of `Asynctask`:

```
..........
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(null);

    if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing()) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    if (isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) { //Triggered NPE
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19915714/1968739), how do I know if `getActivity()` is now attached to the parent activity before calling it?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12402614/2591002)

Comment: Did u add that fragment?

Comment: @SweetWisherツ I replaced it to `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.list_fragment, mFragment, "mFragment").commit();` like from your link. Now the problem is that in my `MyFragment` I am using `getActivity()` somewhere in my code but now it calls `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Now show updated logcat

Comment: Show the line which fires NullPointer Exxception

Comment: @SweetWisherツ Edited already my post

Comment: Does isNetworkAvailable and ur Asynctask reside in same java file??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46916/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-compaq-le2202x)

Answer (score 39):

Before saving the fragment in `onSaveInstanceState` make sure to check if fragment is added to fragment manager

```
@Override 
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (mFragment.isAdded()){
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mFragment", mFragment); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew there would be some way to check this.

Answer (score 3):

I am also facing same problem. WHEN I tried to put fragment in bundleState in

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent",   mContent); //Exception made here
}
```

I checked implementation of `putFragment()` method in `FragmentManager`. It is like

```
 @Override
 public void putFragment(Bundle bundle, String key, Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment.mIndex < 0) {
         throwException(new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + fragment
                    + " is not currently in the FragmentManager"));
    }
    bundle.putInt(key, fragment.mIndex);
  }
```

where `mIndex` is fragment index into active fragment array. So if `mIndex < 0` that means fragment is not currently active. So as @FelipeConde suggested checking `mFragment.isAdded()` could be the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had 2 fragments (**PopularMoviesFragment & TopRatedMoviesFragement**), **PopularMoviesFragment** was populated in onCreate of the Activity and the other will be populated with a click of **BottomNavigationView**.

So When I open the app and without clicking the **BottomNavigationView** if I minimize (or navigate to some other app) I got this Exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment TopRatedMoviesFragement{79d8905} is not currently in the FragmentManager

**My code in onCreate() was**

```
if (currentSelectedbottomNavigation.equals(FRAGMENT_1)) {

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.containerw, fragment_1, FRAGMENT_1)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }else if (currentSelectedbottomNavigation.equals(FRAGMENT_2)){   

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment_2, FRAGMENT_2)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
```

Hence what I did is just added **TopRatedMoviesFragement** and then replaced it by **PopularMoviesFragment**, as shown in below code.

```
if (currentSelectedbottomNavigation.equals(FRAGMENT_1)) {

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, fragment_2, FRAGMENT_2)
                // Its been added to avoid Fragment is not currently in the FragmentManager
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment_1, FRAGMENT_1)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }else if (currentSelectedbottomNavigation.equals(FRAGMENT_2)){  

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment_2, FRAGMENT_2)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
```

Hope this also helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I've faced the same problem .
In my case, I forgot to set mFragment when activity's onBackPressed() is called. That is, when user navigates through A -> B -> C, mFragment is changing accordingly to A, then B, and finally C. However, when back is pressed the current fragment is reversely changing to B, then A, but mFragment is still C. Thus, during onSaveInstanceState, activity tries to save C which is not in the FragmentManager anymore.

> The main point is, you are  probably changing (adding or removing) current [displayed] fragment without appropriately changing mFragment.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Fragments where added to a ViewPager through a FragmentPagerAdapter in order to have multiple tabs, and 1 fragment per Tab.

```
    List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> lsFragments = new List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment>();
    lsFragments.Add(m_FragmentListDocument);
    lsFragments.Add(m_FragmentListNote);
    lsFragments.Add(m_FragmentListRenvoi);

    m_viewPager.Adapter = new TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager, lsFragments, lsTitles);
```

In my OnSaveInstanceState, I wanted to save all tabs, but 1 tab was throwing the Exception `Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment is not currently in the FragmentManager`  :

```
protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);

    SupportFragmentManager.PutFragment(outState, "FragmentListDocument", m_FragmentListDocument);
    SupportFragmentManager.PutFragment(outState, "FragmentListNote", m_FragmentListNote);
    SupportFragmentManager.PutFragment(outState, "FragmentListRenvoi", m_FragmentListRenvoi);
}
```

This is due to the ViewPager : ViewPager loads current fragment shown on screen and (by default) the one to the left and to the right.

So in that case, I modified ViewPager to set OffscreenPageLimit high enough to load all Fragments at startup. Then fragments were added to SupportFragmentManager and Exception was not threw in the OnSaveInstanceState.

```
m_viewPager.OffscreenPageLimit = 4;
```

Hope it will help...